# using user variable in 'IN' clause of sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @A varchar(5000) 
declare @B varchar(5000)

select @A=value from drp.Parameter where parameteridname='IV01'
--result of this query ('DIM003966','DIM000736','DIM025297',
--                                                      'DIM025302','DIM027583')

select [InventLocationId],[WMSLocationId] from ItemKit.InventDim
where inventdimid in (@A)
```

i am not getting any result out of second query but if i run them individually and use result of 1st query in second i am getting it. is there any way around to run them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because it evaluates `@a` as is (as text, not a list of values).

You should create a sql statement on the fly and execute it:

```
declare @sqlStatement nvarchar(4000)

@sqlStatement = 'select [InventLocationId],[WMSLocationId] from ItemKit.InventDim where inventdimid in (' + @A + ')'

execute sp_executesql @sqlStatement
```

But as said by others, don't use unless really necessary.

Comment: Thanks its working but if the value of @A is evaluated as text means its not putting in pattern of 'DIM003966','DIM000736','DIM025297','DIM025302','DIM027583' then in what pattern it gets evaluated

Comment: It isn't evaluated as pattern, just as text.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this code:

```
select [InventLocationId],[WMSLocationId] from ItemKit.InventDim
where inventdimid in (select value from drp.Parameter where parameteridname='IV01')
```

Comment: statement is wrong, the value is a single string (and the the in statement is trying to compare the value 'DIM025302' against ''DIM003966','DIM000736','DIM025297',..' which does not match each other)

Comment: @JayeshShinde Could you run the following statement and tell me what is the output : select Top 10 inventdimid, [InventLocationId],[WMSLocationId] from ItemKit.InventDim

Comment: Axapta  
DIM000001 DCM 
DIM000002 BULK 
DIM000003 BULK Pick
DIM000004 BULK Outbound
DIM000005 TLC 
DIM000006 TLC I
DIM000007 SHIP 
DIM000010 Bulk Receive
DIM000011 shipping P04-3-e

Comment: OK I thought the first query conducted a list of values

Answer (score 0):

As you have a single string value (holding all the values) you could either:

**Parse sql on the fly**

Note: I do not recommend this, as it can allow [sql injection](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&ei=EjN7U6WeJpPy7AbDm4GwDw&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&bvm=bv.67229260,d.ZGU)
(see @Patrick Hofman's answer for good example of this)

**Use like**

```
declare @A varchar(5000) 
declare @B varchar(5000)

select @A=value from drp.Parameter where parameteridname='IV01'
--result of this query ('DIM003966','DIM000736','DIM025297',
--                                                      'DIM025302','DIM027583')

SELECT @A /* Here you will see the problem, as it is not multiple values, 
             it is a single string with a comma & quote (') delimited list */

SELECT 
    [InventLocationId], [WMSLocationId] 
FROM 
    ItemKit.InventDim
WHERE
    /* parse up the inventdimid to include the quote (') around it */
    @A like '%''' + @inventdimid + '''%'
```